# When to use EventGrid and when to use ServiceBus / Storage Queue?

Tags: azure, servicebus, azure-eventgrid

In Azure, we have two separate messaging technologies and it's not very well documented when to use what? While EventGrid is really cool, I did not come across when to use EventGrid(scenarios) vs the Storage/ServiceBus queue? Can someone help?

E.g. if I have the following scenario :

A status of a flag changes and based on that, I want to trigger an algorithm that would do recalculations, few inserts/updates etc. in the database.

For implementing this - I can either use EventGrid or Storage Queue. How do we figure what to use in such scenario? I was looking for some kind of guidance.

Comment: I think this question is quite broad. I would recommend that you edit your question and describe what you're trying to accomplish in more details.

Comment: Edited the question. Can someone help?

Comment: I believe you ended up using the Service bus?

Comment: See comparison article https://build5nines.com/a-tour-of-azure-messaging-services-queues-event-grid-iot-hub-and-more/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basically, Azure Event Grid handles events and Azure ServiceBus handles messages.A message is raw data produced by a service to be consumed or stored. Events are also messages (lightweigth), but they don’t generally convey a publisher intent, other than to inform.

1) If the purpose is to just to store the information ServiceBus can be used.

2) If the information received is used to trigger another service Azure Event Grid can be used.

Find more info here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/compare-messaging-services
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/events-data-points-and-messages-choosing-the-right-azure-messaging-service-for-your-data/

Answer (score 2):

Events are like notifications from a service to inform the world that something happened in the domain of the publisher (similar to an email notification).  There is no expectations from the publisher to have any actions taken.  A message is a command you send to a specific receiver with the expectation of the message to be processed (like an asynchronous post request).

Events will work in pub/sub pattern and multiple subscribers could be configured to the events.  The service that needs to react to an event will get notified by the event grid when an event occurs (http call from event grid to the receiver).  The event will remain in the event grid until deletion (cleanup) and there is no garantie of keeping the original order (no FIFO).

In the other hand, messages will be added to a queue and will be deleted once the “message processor” is done with it.  The messages in the queue will keep the original order (FIFO).  The message processor has to pull messages from the queue.

In your scenario, you could use a combination of both.  Service A sends an event “StatusChanged”, then you can configure a subscription to that event and send a message to a queue, then have your logic to process that message.  This will end up with a fully async communication pattern.  This is ideal to support scenarios where you processor is down or too busy.  The incoming messages will simply get accumulated in the queue and eventually being processed once the service is back up and running.  And without affecting the original service that sent the “StatusChanged” event..